# How to translate a set so it would update its children and vice-versa in RaphaelJS?

Tags: canvas, svg, raphael

I'll start by presenting my fiddle. It will make my problem clear:
http://jsfiddle.net/fnwcu2yu/

```
paper=Raphael(0, 30, 500, 500)
    handle=[]
    all=paper.set()
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        handle[i]=paper.circle(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200),Math.floor(Math.random() * 200)+40,5)
        //keeps starting position on dragStart
        handle[i].sx = 0
        handle[i].sy = 0
        //keeps total translation throughout
        handle[i].tx = 0
        handle[i].ty = 0
        all.push(handle[i])

    }
    all.attr("fill","black")
     all.sx = 0
     all.sy = 0


    all.drag(
            function (dx, dy) {
                this.tx = this.sx + dx
                this.ty = this.sy + dy
                this.transform(["t", this.tx, this.ty])
                },
            function () {
                this.sx = this.tx
                this.sy = this.ty
                },
            function () { }
                )

    moveRight = function() {
        changeX=20
        changeY=0
        all.sx=all.sx+changeX
        all.sx=all.sx+changeY
        all.transform(["T", all.sx, all.sy])


    }
```

I have created 5 circle. each of them is draggable. You can drag each circle individually.

Also, I've created a set called 'all'.
When you apply transformations to the set, it affects all of its children. 
So far, so good.

I created a button that translates the entire set 20 pixels to the right.

**Problem 1:** It works fine if I haven't moved any of the circles, but if I do move a circle and press the button, it moves 20 pixels to the right **from its original position** instead of the current position.

**Problem 2:** once I do the set translation and try to drag a circle, it also jumps to its original position (before translation) and starts the movement from there.

I have found a (probably) bad way to solve problem 2, but I guess this is not how it's supposed to work.

See solution in second fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fnwcu2yu/1/

I have a solution for both problems but it's a cheat. I am almost certain Raphael has a better mechanism for dealing with this type of thing.

What I ended up doing, is not translate the set, but the individual objects in it, one by one.

```
moveRight = function() {
            changeX=20
            changeY=0

            for(i=0;i<handle.length;i++) {
            handle[i].tx=handle[i].tx+changeX
            handle[i].ty=handle[i].ty+changeY
            handle[i].transform(["T", handle[i].tx, handle[i].ty])
            }
```

See solved (hacked) fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fnwcu2yu/2/

Am I wrong?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Personally I think the last solution is fine, a set just iterates over the elements anyway. You could change "T" to "...T" or "...t" for example, so the transform is takes into consideration other transforms, but then you will need to adjust the dragging a bit.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this without appending (Which I achieved thus far). Transform strings can become super long, and I'm trying to avoid the load on the system

Comment: Are you sure they are appending, I thought it just redid the matrix ? Where are you seeing that in the DOM or object ?

Comment: "..." is a prefix for append/prepend

@Ian

Comment: Indeed it is...but where are you seeing super long strings and not just a computed matrix ?

Comment: Every movement, and every rotation and every scale accumulates. After a while on very interactive paper, you would get really long strings. 

What I try to achieve is calculate the transforms the object is going to go through and add them up so I end up with 1 translation, 1 rotation, and 1 scale. 

This is part of a much larger app, and I have been able to achieve this by pre-calculating where the object is going to end-up and I am trying to apply the same thing here, but I might be hoping for too much.

Comment: I'm just asking where you see that string, out of interest ?

Comment: @Ian Paper.el.transform() would return the entire transformation string

Comment: Ok interesting, I'm more familiar with Snap, so hadn't spotted that happening. Only other thing a little 'simpler' code wise I can think of is something like http://jsfiddle.net/fnwcu2yu/9/ Not sure if thats quite what you are looking for though, as you still end up looping through the elements as opposed to treating as a set.

Comment: That definitely seems to work :)

I wonder if when moving the entire set, it still does a "behind the scene" operation on every individual element or not. What is a set in Raphael is not very clear to me.

Comment: I think of it as just like an array really, that you can apply element methods to, which then iterate over all the elements. Problem is, I don't think there's any method which transforms relative to its existing matrix, so I think you will have to loop one way or another. Another subtle difference would be to use the set forEach like http://jsfiddle.net/fnwcu2yu/10/

Comment: I created a new question that might be of interest to you too. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489224/in-raphael-or-even-generally-in-svg-do-transforms-take-less-cpu-then-re-positio

Comment: One last thing, if you are doing this a lot, you can extend a set method, like http://jsfiddle.net/fnwcu2yu/11/