# In Raphael or even Generally in SVG, do transforms take less CPU then re-positioning manually?

Tags: svg, raphael

I am trying to figure out what are the implications for using transform in raphael vs. actually moving the object manually.

For example, here is a circle.

```
circ = Paper.circle(0,0,5)
```

Now I can move the circle in two ways.

```
1. circ.transform(['t',5,0])
2. circ.attr("x",5)
```

Is one superior to the other **CPU-wise**?

Same question with rotation. Here's a rectangle(path):

```
pathRect=paper.path(['m',0,0,'l'10,0,10,10,0,10,'z'])
```

I want to rotate it 45 degrees. I can do it two way:

```
1. pathRect.transform(['r',45])
2. calculating the position of the four corners using this formula:
    pointOnCircleByAngle = function (cx,cy,r,angle) {
    x=cx + (r * Math.cos(mathUtils.rad(angle)))
    y=cy + (r * Math.sin(mathUtils.rad(angle)))
    return {x:x,y:y}
```

As mentioned in the svg reference, this is the formula used for rotations any way, **So** is using transforms is  only a way to achieve the same goal with less code, or is it has other benefits towards saving cpu/processing power

Thanks :)

Comment: My gut instinct would be transforms would be slower (but probably not noticeable), than manipulating an attribute (but may be faster if doing the same thing like rotation, i.e. browser code vs user code). However, if performance is key, I would be tempted to take a peek at css transforms on svg elements, especially if on mobile. (check compatibility with what you need to do and browser), it can often be quicker.

Comment: Try it and see. The actual answer depends on which browser, which version of that browser, which operating system, which graphics card etc, etc.

Comment: @RobertLongson so there isn't a clear-cut answer I gather. One is not inherently superior than the other. Is that right?

Comment: If there is one today it might be wrong in the next browser version.